# Apple receipt validation for iOS7. Add libcrypto.a and libssl.a libraries to XCode project

Tags: ios, openssl, in-app-purchase, asn.1, receipt

I need to validate in-app purchase receipts. Apple has released a new approach for receipts, now the receipts can be stored on device in NSBundle. It requires OpenSSL and ASN1 be added to XCode project in order to encode and validate the receipts. I have been searching online for possible solution. No luck(. If anybody has done it already, please help.
1. I need to use OpenSSL and ASN1, add libraries libcrypto.a and libssl.a
2. Write a code for validating receipts for iOS7.

Answer (score 4):

I used ASN1 from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/asn1c/

This is what I used for OpenSSL: http://www.cvursache.com/2013/08/13/How-To-Build-openssl-For-iOS/

As for deep information on using OpenSSL, and ASN1, I'd like to know if you find a comprehensive source for that. I cobbled what I could together from various sources. I looked at:

1. WWDC 2013 session "Using Receipts to Protect Your Digital Sales".
2. https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS
3. http://www.umich.edu/~x509/ssleay/x509_store.html
4. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html
5. [How to print a BIO object in opensl or print time from ASN1_TYPE object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630300/how-to-print-a-bio-object-in-opensl-or-print-time-from-asn1-type-object)
6. http://lionet.info/asn1c/asn1c-usage.html#SECTION02211000000000000000
7. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html
8. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html
9. [IA5STRING ASN.1 coding format: in-app purchase receipt validation and decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435259/ia5string-asn-1-coding-format-in-app-purchase-receipt-validation-and-decoding)
10. [How to format convert the string 2013-01-27T02:31:47+08:00 into NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447693/how-to-format-convert-the-string-2013-01-27t0231470800-into-nsdate)
11. http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will found what you are looking for here :

http://ataugeron.github.io/blog/blog/2013/09/23/app-store-receipt-validation-on-ios-7/

Comment: Yeh, I've seen that link before. The link does not have detailed and deep information on using OpenSSL and ASN1. Alsoo, there is no explanation of adding libcrypto.a and libssl.a libraries to XCode project.

Comment: Aaand the site is gone.